# Flutter How to show multiple tooltip at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `just_the_tooltip` Flutter package to show tooltip in Flutter maps.
[image]

It is working fine but what I want is to show multiple tooltips at the same time. In this case, when one is clicked while the other is active, the previous one disappears. Also I tried other packages but tooltip does not move or scroll with the movement of map.

Comment: Could you share some snippets so we can help?

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be to use `google_maps_flutter` package instead of `Flutter maps` (unless you don't have a choice) mainly because of the reasons described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64675568/21408550).

The `google_maps_flutter` package already provides something called as an `InfoWindow` which is nothing but a `tooltip` that will be displayed when you click on the `Marker`.

For more information, please check this [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/InfoWindow-class.html).

Comment: Actually I need to use flutter maps because I am not using Google maps.